# javascript-Chart.js v4.4.0 How to update additional data?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

It seems like you're managing multiple charts by dividing items in a single dataset.
However, you're encountering errors whenever new data is added.

```
            let category = [];
            let h2s = [];
            let co = [];
            let co2 = [];
            let ch4 = [];
            let no2 = [];
            let so2 = [];

            for (let row of result) {
                h2s.push(row.h2s);
                co.push(row.co);
                co2.push(row.co2);
                ch4.push(row.ch4);
                no2.push(row.no2);
                so2.push(row.so2);
                const time = moment(row.updateDate).format('HH:mm:ss');
                category.push(time);
            }

            let h2sData = {
                labels  : category,
                datasets: [{
                    label      : 'H2S',
                    data       : h2s,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                }]
            };

            let coData = {
                labels  : category,
                datasets: [{
                    label      : 'CO',
                    data       : co,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 132, 1)',
                }]
            };

            let no2Data = {
                labels  : category,
                datasets: [{
                    label      : 'NO2',
                    data       : no2,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 155, 132, 1)',
                }]
            };

            let ch4Data = {
                labels  : category,
                datasets: [{
                    label      : 'CH4',
                    data       : ch4,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
                }]
            };

            let co2Data = {
                labels  : category,
                datasets: [{
                    label      : 'CO2',
                    data       : co2,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 155, 132, 1)',
                }]
            };

            let so2Data = {
                labels  : category,
                datasets: [{
                    label      : 'SO2',
                    data       : so2,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 155, 132, 1)',
                }]
            };

            initializeGraph('graph1', h2sData);
            initializeGraph('graph2', coData);
            initializeGraph('graph3', co2Data);
            initializeGraph('graph4', ch4Data);
            initializeGraph('graph5', no2Data);
            initializeGraph('graph6', so2Data);

    function initializeGraph(containerId, data) {
        let ctx = $(`#${containerId}`).get(0).getContext('2d');
        let chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: data,
        });
        chart.push(chartInstance);
    }

function addChartData(label, newData) {
      const time = moment(label).format('HH:mm:ss');
        const gas = ['H2S', 'CO', 'CO2', 'CH4', 'NO2', 'SO2'];

        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            chart[i].data.labels.push(time);
            console.log(chart[i].data.labels)
            chart[i].data.datasets[0].data.push(newData[gas[i]]);
            chart[i].update();
        }

}
```

It seems like the bug is occurring in the last function, addChartData, where a new label is being added each time an update is performed.

[image]

It seems that even when using chart.update(), it's causing errors.(TypeError: chart.update is not a function) .... ;;